# Why does excel change rows in formulas in this case

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have the following workbook:

`Sheet 1` contains a series of informations row by row with several cells per row.
`Sheet Formulas 1` contains a series of formulas formatting the data in `Sheet 1` respecting the row by row logic.
`Sheet 2` again has formulas that will fill the rows with data from `Sheet 1` and `Sheet Formulas 1` depending in different calculations and conditions from both Sheets.

As you can imagine in row 2 of `Sheet 2` (row 1 being the headers) the formulas look like:

```
=if(sheet1!A2=blabla;bli;blu)   =if(sheet1!B2=blabla;"";"Cool")

=if(sheet1!A3=blabla;bli;blu)   =if(sheet1!B3=blabla;"";"Cool")

...and so on. Up to 3000 rows.
```

I have a few users manipulating this file from a shared network drive and it's been a few times already that the formulas seem to have "moved up". Last time, in both `Sheet Formulas 1` and `Sheet 2`, in row 2 I found the references for row 6, in row 3 for row 7 etc. They all correlate all the way down to 3004.

Weird enough there is a special formula in `Sheet 2` that contains both a reference to `Sheet 1` and to `Sheet Formula 1` and the "moving up" only happens with the reference to `Sheet 1`, resulting for row 2: `=if(Sheet1!A6;Sheet Formula 1!A2)`. It feels like this detail is very relevant to understand what is going on.

That is precisely my question. **Does someone know what can be happening and how can I prevent it?** *Precision: The users are not at all knowledgeable about excel beyond some basics.*

Comment: "Example of Normal Relative and Absolute (Locked) Cell References" at https://www.exceltactics.com/lock-cell-formula-references-table-columns-excel/ ?

Comment: I don't mean this to sound like a lecture, but the sentence "a few users manipulating this file" and "the users are not at all knowledgeable about excel" means this will not be a robust business process.  For simplicity, a spreadsheet *completely* intermingles the code and the data.  That's insanely powerful when well understood.  But it's unlikely a lay-user will understand the implications of adding or moving cells, and thus very likely they'll corrupt your logic frequently.

Comment: Consider fixing the file and locking all cells that should not be touched by the users